# Trouble merging data in SPSS

Tags: python, merge, spss

I have two datasets, let's call them `D1` and `D2`. `D2`contains a couple of variables I want to add to `D1`. `D2` is essentially a restricted set of the data from `D1`, but with an extra variable. Problem is, I can't seem to use `Merge` because the `Name` string variable has been switched in `D2`. As in, in `D1` each entry of the variable `Name` reads as `Word1 Word2`, whereas in `D2` it reads as `Word2 Word1`.

How can I find the entries in `D1` which also occur in `D2`, and add their missing variables from `D2`?

Very happy to use Python to solve this if needed.

Comment: for all the string variable names, the width should be same and then you can merge .  you can use alter type function eg alter type var1 (A 600).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets create a working example:

```
data list list/name (a20) v1 (f1) v2(f1).
begin data
"hello world" 1 2
"huff puff" 3 4
"word1 word2" 5 6
end data.
dataset name D1.

data list list/name (a20) y1 (f1) y2(f1).
begin data
"world hello" 11 12
"puff huff" 13 14
"word2 word1" 15 16
end data.
dataset name D2.
```

Now we want to match the two files using `name` as key, but the words in `name` are reversed in D2. So first we have to put them back in order, by taking the second word and putting it in front of the first:

```
dataset activate D2.
rename variables name=Rname.
string name #n1 #n2(a20).
compute #n2=substr(Rname,1,index(Rname," ")).
compute #n1=substr(Rname,index(Rname," ")+1,20).
compute name=concat(rtrim(#n1), " ", rtrim(#n2)).
sort cases by name.
```

Now we can proceed to match the files:

```
dataset activate D1.
sort cases by name.
match files /file=* /tab=D2/by name/drop rname.
exe.
```